# I am also resigning as a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

An election is a big process for the community (and for SE team to set up), and now that Qiaochu's resignation will set one in motion, I am going to take the opportunity to resign as well.

To be clear: I don't have any specific complaint, I'm not making a principled stand for or against something, I'm not in trouble with the SE people, and I'm not leaving out of disagreement or exasperation with any user or fellow moderator. I've just put enough of my own time and effort into it at this point, and I'd like to focus on doing well in grad school. There are plenty of other people who will do a good job as a moderator.

I do plan to continue participating as a normal user.

Comment: My upvote is a sign of appreciation for all the hard work you've put into this site and all the great questions/answers you've posted.  Thanks for your service, and I wish you well in the future.

Comment: May I resign as a moderator as well?

Comment: Thank you, also, for taking on a thankless job, and I wish you all the best in your grad studies.

Comment: @WillJagy, didn't you mean, "May I re-sign as moderator"?

Comment: I don't think Qiaochu's resignation would have set an election in motion, but as I recall one was supposed to be happening pretty soon. How about you postpone this until there's a date for the election?

Comment: Also, many thanks for all the hard work!

Comment: @FredKline, that doesn't work either, I've never signed or posted anything that could be interpreted as an intent to become a moderator. As my brother was leaving the Navy, they made attractive offers for him to re-up, but he had been having a miserable time. Also, as my father pointed out, the days of internal promotion to officer were long over.

Comment: @Will: YVAN EHT NIOJ.

Comment: @Asaf: The moderators were informed by the SE team that there would be an election soon after Qiaochu announced his resignation; also, I have sent an email to them about my resignation, but I have not heard back yet regarding when I will have my diamond removed. I assume it will be at the same time as Qiaochu's is, and that this will be whenever the election is ready to go.

Comment: @Zev: [Qiaochu indicates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9267/8348) that he expects his ♦ to disappear quite soon.  Will an election actually begin that quickly?

Comment: Thanks for all the work. As far as I can judge, you've been a great moderator.

Comment: Also, thanks for all the hard work!

Comment: @ArthurFischer: as far as I am aware, not _that_ quickly. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: What do you mean do "*An election is a big process for the community (and for SE team to set up)*..."?

Comment: thanks for all the hard work!

Comment: @ArthurFischer Barring any changes after our team meeting today, we have an election scheduled to begin next week.

Comment: @Anna: With three moderators out, we're pretty much back to the number of moderators we had when I wrote my thread about expanding the moderator team a year ago. How many slots will you open now, considering that usually slots are just added rather than replaced?

Comment: @Thomas: I just mean that questioning the candidates on their positions and deciding who to vote for (hopefully) contains a non-trivial amount of thought on the part of voters, and (regretably) contains a non-trivial amount of drama, so it would not make sense to go through a full election and then, soon afterwards, start a new one. Additionally, my understanding is that it involves some work and preparation for the SE team to set up, which is another reason not to hold more elections than necessary.

Comment: You were a great moderator. All the best for Grad School.

Comment: Dear @ZevChonoles: You were one of the nicest people in MSE, especially to new users. Hopefully your successor will follow your footsteps. Congratulations on a job well done!

Comment: @AsafKaragila 4 slots in this round. This should put us at the existing team + 1 when all is said and done. While it's tempting to elect more, we refrain from introducing too many new moderators to the team at one time. Doing that tends to mess with the learning curve the new folks have and the overall consistency of moderation. However, if there's additional demand, we can (and have in the past) appoint more folks from the runners up for a few months after the election before the results go stale.

Comment: @Anna, I remember how mixedmath and robjohn got their diamond, yes. I hope that this batch of new moderators will be more open to accepting that they don't know everything, or that you may have prepared a "diamond bootcamp" for handling flags and whatnot.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, it's up to you guys as a community to elect folks who exhibit the characteristics you all find valuable in a moderator - such as being open to criticism. :)

Comment: @Anna: No problem! Give me a vote worth 5000 others! :-)

Comment: Sorry to see you go. Your balanced approach will be missed.

Comment: I am a new member here, but I could  appreciate your approach to problem solving every time I read your answers/comments and hints. I wish you all the best for your graduate school period!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[image: I have zero useful things to say. Just posting a screencap of the comment section so there's something in this post. This way this Question can get off the "Unanswered List"]

Comment: (just to get this off the unanswered list. Please vote this up)

Comment: Cripes, Willie, you scared me there for a moment! I thought you were gonna quit as well.