# 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2013 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://math.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I'm sure @TheChaz2.0 knows this, but in case others don't: All nominations are self-nominations.

Comment: @Asaf: indeed - would have been better left for my weekly SE 12-step meeting :)

Comment: @TheChaz: Tell them I'm not coming this week. :-)

Answer (score 5):

From [here](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#math.stackexchange), I see that there are $4$ moderator positions available. I believe this should be increased by at least one, i.e., there should be at least $5$ moderator positions available for this election.

The reason is that, till about couple of weeks back, there were a total of $7$ moderators. [Qiaochu Yuan resigned as a moderator a week back](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9267/i-am-resigning-as-moderator). [Zev](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9282/i-am-also-resigning-as-a-moderator?lq=1) and [Eric](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9291/change-of-moderators-i-resign-as-well?lq=1) have also indicated that they will resign once this election is done. Hence, there is an outflow of $3$ moderators, whereas there is an inflow of only $4$ moderators, and thereby at the end of all this, there will be only $8$ moderators. I believe $8$ moderators are not sufficient to moderate this site. Every moderator election on math.stackexchange.com since $2010$, has seen the moderator count increase by $2$.

Comment: Anna Lear (an SE community manager) [has mentioned in a  comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9282/i-am-also-resigning-as-a-moderator#comment33654_9282) that if they feel it is necessary, the SE team might appoint more moderators using the most current election result (if those results aren't too old).

Comment: I'm on the fence about this. In terms of *turnaround*, we are experiencing a lot in a short time. So maybe we could have just a "replacement" election, and then have another (regular) election in 6 months for 2-3 more slots. Or does the present high demand outweigh the feeling of too many changes at once?

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks. I did not see the comment before.

Comment: @TheChaz: I don't think that would be a good idea. Elections are one nasty business. I think that the solution of giving four slots, and increasing those in the near future if deemed necessary is an excellent idea. If anything, however, I think that there should be a reasonable time in which some evaluation is done by the community managers with the new moderators and the old and see whether or not things work out well or that additional help is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have a question on how the top $10$ primary candidates will proceed to the election phase. The election page says

$\color{red}{\text{After 4 days, the top 10 candidates based on primary vote score proceed onward to the election}}$
$\color{red}{\text{phase.}}$

Let us consider two candidates:

- The first candidate has $200$ upvotes and $190$ downvotes (hence his total score is $10$).
- The second candidate has $20$ upvotes and $5$ downvotes (his total score is $15$).

Who gets the nod to proceed to the election phase? Where can I find more information on the details of the election procedure, in general?

Comment: I have a feeling that this should be a separate question on meta, with the [tag:election] tag.